# Crash proof, high availability linux based OS

Tags: linux, operating-system

I've a system which should run in autarky (no internet connection) in an environment of unstable power supply (several outage per month). The system runs permanently python scripts (over several months the same script)
At the moment I've the problem, that the install linux-based OS has problem with that environement as:

- Performs a disk check after outage => takes several hours
- During boot time, F1 for a regular boot has to be pressed(!)
- Booting ends up in a loop due to "something?"

What I'm looking for is a system that:

- recovers the last running action and continuous it
- does not need any user interaction after reboot

Is there such a high-availability linux-based operating system which offers this?

Comment: It's not he linux, but the configuration of it. Any Linux can fulfill your needs.

Comment: Okay good to know! But can you get me a hint in which direction I have to search? Settings, Filesystem etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look for an UPS to shutdown gracefully and restart when the power get back (I think some can be connected to the pc and generate events that can be handled by the system)

You could look for some root-readonly configuration to minimize the disk check time to the writable partition only, live distros or distros for embedded devices, that eventually can run on readonly devices and write only user data to a disk partition, mount the writable partition with the sync option to minimize data loss, but without an UPS and unexpected outages I don't think you can guarantee data safety and status coherency, the probability to get a data loss only depends on how much data your scripts write.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. A UPS would have been my first choice, but I've a very limited amount of space, so that's why I hoped for a software only solution. But will for sure look in the other option you've suggested!